# Custom Controls in Xamarin iOS with MVVMCross and no XIB

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin, mvvmcross

I am following a code only approach for my Xamarin iOS app and can see how you can easily create control such as UILabel and UITextField in ViewDidLoad of a Controller. That is also where I can apply MVVMCross Fluent Binding.

I have seen Stuart's [n19](http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2013/05/n19-custom-controls-on-ios-n1-days-of.html) where he creates a custom Circle View and one that creates a Custom Label.

- The custom circle overrides the Draw method and draws a circle (Owner Draw)
- The custom labels changes the Forecolor of the existing Label (Subclassed)

I don't feel that either of those works for me. I want to create a UIView that is made up of other controls, a composite control. Imagine a control that looked something like this. That would be an ImageView, and 4 labels with one of them clickable.

[image]

At what point in the life of the UIView would I create something like that. Is there an equivalent of ViewDidLoad?

Comment: Maybe try http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2013/06/n32-truth-about-viewmodels-starring.html

Comment: Thanks Stuart, bang on as ever

Comment: @Stuart at 21m35s in N32 you say that MvxView is a quick and useful alternative to building a UserControl. Is there a UserControl alternative for Xamarin iOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Stuart said in his comment, [N=32 - ViewModels and MvxView on the iPad - N+1 days of MvvmCross](http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2013/06/n32-truth-about-viewmodels-starring.html) 
 is the MVVMCross tutorial you want.

For those that are happy with the idea of ViewModels being more than just a ViewModel per screen and understand Binding the bit around Custom Views starts at [minute 20](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cYu_9rcAJU4&t=20m0s)